# Scala create List[Int]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I quickly create a `List[Int]` that has 1 to 100 in it?

I tried `List(0 to 100)`, but it returns `List[Range.Inclusive]`

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try

```
(0 to 100).toList
```

The code you tried is creating a list with a single element - the range.  You might also be able to do

```
List(0 to 100:_*)
```

**Edit**

The `List(...)` call takes a variable number of parameters (`xs: A*`).  Unlike varargs in Java, even if you pass a `Seq` as a parameter (a `Range` is a `Seq`), it will still treat it as the first element in the varargs parameter.  The `:_*` says "treat this parameter as the entire varargs `Seq`, not just the first element".

If you read `: A*` as "an (`:`) 'A' (`A`) repeated (`*`)", you can think of `:_*` as "as (`:`) 'something' (`_`) repeated (`*`)"

Comment: Thanks, what does :_* do in List(0 to 100:_*) ?

Comment: Hmm. This returns type `List[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive]` for me. @Eastsun seems to return the correct type.

Answer (score 13):

```
List.range(1,101)
```

The second argument is exclusive so this produces a list from 1 to 100.